# Canvas/Context issues

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a document using the  tag and am having an issue.
I have declared canvas and context as global variables and am filling them in my initial function.  This seems to work partially, but certain functions (for instance, one calling the canvas width) are giving me the error: *"Cannot call method getAttribute on null"*

Is this because I have tried setting up the document in this way?  I tried filling them when defined (like they can be for a local variable) but this seemed to produce just as many errors!

I am declaring the variables like so:

```
var canvas = null;
var context = null;
```

And filling them in the function which is linked to the body onload like so:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("imageDisplay");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Should I be re-filling them like this for every function that uses them?

I was using almost the exact same methods in another piece of script yesterday which worked fine!  I don't understand what I've done wrong!

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to set the variables again within functions, if you declared them globally they should be globally accessible.

Can you be more specific about the functions in which the variables don't work? 

Also, when you say you have declared them as global variables, how exactly did you do this, and where?

Comment: i may be using the wrong terminology, I'm not sure if they're truly global with javascript?  I'm declaring them outside all of my functions (at the top of the document).  The functions where I am having an issue are functions where I am accessing attributes of the variables - so for instance when I'm trying to get the width of the canvas using "var something = canvas.width"

Comment: That's one way of making them global, the other is to simply reference them inside a function but without the Var keyword. Do you have any more details about the function they do not work in? What kind of function is it, and when does it get called?

Comment: What you are doing should work fine; you will need to provide a reproducible test case, or a link to your code (preferably pared down) for further help.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue might be a scoping issue.

root or window javascript

```
var canvas;
var context;
canvas = document.getElementById("imageDisplay");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

foo();
```

function foo

```
foo{
    canvas = document.getElementById("imageDisplay");//errors
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
}
```

If my understanding (both of javascript and your issue) is correct canvas isn't defined because foo.canvas is different from window.canvas.   You either need to re-declare canvas and context in foo, or use window.canvas and window.context, or pass in those variables. I am a bit of a novice at javascript so hopefully someone else can intercede